# What is the effective way to study and understand <script> used in a website through the firebug?

Tags: javascript

I am newbie. I want to know how to effectively understand, the scripts used in the website through the use of Firebug. I have no knowledge of Javascript. 
Or what do i first need to learn to be able to understand these scripts? How to sift through study material that is particularly related to website design, which i should study, to grasp the understanding of various methods and techniques used there?

For example: (i have put dots in link two to obscure the ssl and www)

> var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
>   *"https://...." : "http://...")*; document.write(unescape("%3Cscript
>   src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'
>   type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

How it works and What does it do? It is so overwhelming to find these kind of chunks of scripts. Please share with me, how you would go about it. I know HTML and CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- `var gaJsHost = ...`: Sets `gaJsHost` to either the HTTP or HTTPS location of the JS file.
- `document.write(...` writes a `<script>` tag that loads the JS file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was helpful.  What i understand is, the gaJsHost is the 'tracking' host from Google Analytics? and it sets or tracks whether the location of url is secure or unsecure? in addition to that tracking other user behaviors. Did further search and found this : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/  Thanks again!